# How to identify the subset of a large dataset that has a similar distribution with the another dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, distributions, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement [**transfer learning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) to make predictions on test set using a model trained on another dataset collected from a different sample.

For this, I need to identify the subset of training data that has a similar distribution with the test data.

I wonder if there are any methods to achieve this in `sklearn` or `python`. `R` also works. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: How many dimensions does the RV have?

Comment: @AmiTavory what is `RV`? I have around 30 columns in the data set (I hope this answers your question).

Comment: Yes, that answers it, thanks. (RV = random variable/vector.)

Comment: @AmiTavory do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For lower dimensions, maybe. I'm afraid my idea would badly break in 30 dimensions. Sorry. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you have density functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ for your training and testing distributions, you can subsample the training set to match the distribution of the testing distribution as described in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286062/distribution-matching-by-subsampling) question.  The linked question provides code for doing exactly this in the case where you have a single dimension, and as long as the dimension is not too high for density estimation to work, it may work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I am a novice Python user, but I do use R a great deal. I know that isn't what you were looking for and this suggestion may only tangentially relate to your question. That all being said, you could consider using a model-based clustering approach. As opposed to say, k-means, which does not incorporate variable distributions in its clustering decisions, something like a [latent profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) or [latent class analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model) may be more in line with what you are looking for as centroids, variances, and covariances are all considered when probabilistically assigning cases to subpopulations. These approaches can distinguish between two groups that may be similar in their average scores on a given set of variables, but show evidence of different variances and covariances on those same variables (not a perfect mapping on to your question of matching distributions, but perhaps a step closer?)

If possible, you may also want to reduce the dimensionality of the data set using something like a principal components analysis, though I understand that may not an option.

I am less certain about the capabilities of Python, but R the `mclust` package allows for model-based clustering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder if you know of any libraries from `R` for this purpose?

Comment: One is `mclust` which works on continuous variables. Another is `poLCA` which is appropriate for polytomous variables. Additionally (despite being new to Bayesian analyses), I do imagine there is a way of approaching this problem from a Bayesian perspective, though I fear I am not experienced enough in those methods to see it. I know that Bayesian models can be used for identification of latent classes, the question is whether there is a way to modify them to identify groups with particular distributional properties across variables. I am sure there is a way, but then I always am.